# Birt report how to write mongodb db command

Tags: eclipse, mongodb, birt

I want to import report query from js file.

To do that I am choosing `Run Database Command` command type. But I dont know how to write the query.

I tried sth like this `db.user.find({})` blindly but that does not work.

Any doc/resource on using this feature?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you select `Run Database Command` you enter a valid JSON-Object in the Expression. This Object will be executed in a call to [`db.runCommand()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.runCommand/), a MongoDB interface to execute Non-CRUD operations.

Enter `{ isMaster: 1 }` and you will see the Result

```
{
    "ismaster" : true,
    "maxBsonObjectSize" : 16777216,
    "maxMessageSizeBytes" : 48000000,
    "maxWriteBatchSize" : 1000,
    "localTime" : ISODate("2016-04-26T16:24:18.317Z"),
    "maxWireVersion" : 3,
    "minWireVersion" : 0,
    "ok" : 1
}
```

**Update** to read the intention of what you want to achieve:

Select the *empty line* from Command Type and enter the name of the collection you want to use in the line above. Click on `$query Expression...` and add the JSON-Object to restrict your query. Then select from the displayed attributes the one you want to add to your result set.

[image: birt mongoDB query]